# TIF Compress CCITT4

Tags: c#, compression, tiff, image-compression

I m trying to compress tiff file with CCITT4. Original size 101 KB, after run size reduce a little 98 KB. My limit size 50 KB, how can I make the size under my limit? code is below

My limits;
Size <50KB
Image Width: 1766 – 1890 pixels 
Image Length: 915 – 1040 pixels

Thanks everyone.
[Image Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZAx3.png)

```
public static Byte[] CompressBitmap(Bitmap img)
    {
        Bitmap bm = img;
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        ImageCodecInfo ici = null;
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.MimeType == "image/tiff")
                ici = codec;
        }

        EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, 
                    (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, 
                    (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bm.Save(stream, ici, ep);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: These are black and white images right?

Comment: Right, black and white images, also i have dimension limits (1766, 915)

Comment: What is the source Image PixelFormat set to? Have you tried RLE compression? Do you need just the byte array or do you generate a new Image? In this case, what is the PixelFormat after the new Image is generated?

Comment: Also, Group 4 generates a pretty low quality Image. Are you sure you want this? Do you need these Images to have the TIFF format, or another format may also do (if you care more about compression)?

Comment: Exactly i dont know the source image PixelFormat, first I resize source image and clone it then run compress algorithm. I need byte array at the end, but dont try RLE compression, I should compress result file with CCITT4.

can i use PixelFormat to reduce the size?

Comment: What are the actual operations that this process is meant to perform? Do you need to compress Images, so they're smaller, or do you need to generate `CCITT Group 4` (Fax quality) Images for some reason? G3, G4 and RLE only work with B/W Images (as 1bpp Indexed). If PixelFormat is something else, the Encoder falls back to the Default for the format. Update your question to specify the actual requirements. As a note, you *may* have better results using the [System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffBitmapEncoder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapencoder)

Comment: My source images size bigger than 50KB or dimensions bigger than limits 
Image Width: 1766 – 1890 pixels
Image Length: 915 – 1040 pixels
I have to resize images in limits and reduce size under 50 KB, and black white images. Also - Image compression algorithm: CCITT Group 4 Fax

You are right I will update my question with this values.

Comment: I added sample.

Answer (score 0):

Since the source Image seems to be a Color Image (that just happens to look like  Black&White) and its dimensions need to be adjusted to a maximum value, you need to:

1. Redefine proportionally the Size of the source Image, setting the maximum Width and Height limits that the converted image needs to respect
2. Convert the Image to a `1bpp Indexed` format: the [Bitmap.Clone()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.clone) method provides means to both define the source Image new Size and set a specific [PixelFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat) (**`PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed`**, in this case). The internal conversion method is quite good, the resulting Image quality is usually a good compromise.
3. Define the [quality of the Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.quality): since the Image will be converted to B&W, its *quality* can be set initially to the maximum (`100`). The process can be repeated if the final Image bytes count doesn't fit the requirements (`50KB`)
4. [Compress the Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression) using the CCTII Group 4 [Compression scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encodervalue)
5. [Encode the Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo), using the TIFF format Encoder, saving it to a `MemoryStream` for further processing

The size in bytes of the sample Image provided in the question, when saved to a file, is reduced from the initial **`94,600`** bytes to **`6,786`** bytes with maximum quality.

```
File.WriteAllBytes("[Image Path].tiff", imageStream.ToArray());
```

The **`ConvertToBWTiffImageStream()`** method can be called as:

```
var maximumWidthAndHeight = new Size(1024, 768);
int quality = 100;
var compression = EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4;
var imageStream = ConvertToBWTiffImageStream(sourceImage, maximumWidthAndHeight, quality, compression);
```

Note that **`maximumWidthAndHeight`** specify the maximum Width and the maximum Height, not a new Size of the Image (which would be otherwise distorted). The Image Size is scaled proportionally according to these values.

---

► Remember to add this: **`using ImageCodec = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder;`**

<sub>(the **`GetImageMaxSize()`** method is half-dumb, I'll fix it later)</sub>

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using ImageCodec = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder;

private MemoryStream ConvertToBWTiffImageStream(Bitmap image, Size maxWidthHeight, long compressionLevel, EncoderValue compressionScheme)
{
    var imageSize = GetImageMaxSize(image, maxWidthHeight);
    var bwImage = image.Clone(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size), PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
    compressionLevel = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(100, compressionLevel));

    var codecParms = new EncoderParameters(2);
    try {
        var imageCodec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(enc => enc.FormatID == ImageFormat.Tiff.Guid);
        var qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(ImageCodec.Quality, compressionLevel);
        var compressionParam = new EncoderParameter(ImageCodec.Compression, (long)compressionScheme);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        codecParms.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        codecParms.Param[1] = compressionParam;
        image.Save(ms, imageCodec, codecParms);
        return ms;
    }
    finally {
        codecParms.Dispose();
        bwImage.Dispose();
    }
}

private Size GetImageMaxSize(Image image, Size maxSize)
{
    float scale = 1.0f;
    if (image.Width > maxSize.Width && image.Width >= image.Height) {
        scale = (float)maxSize.Width / image.Width;
    }
    else if (image.Height > maxSize.Height) {
        scale = (float)maxSize.Height / image.Height;
    }
    return new Size((int)(image.Width * scale), (int)(image.Height * scale));
}
```